# ANTLR4 Grammar for field validation

Tags: angular, typescript, grammar, antlr4, lex

I'm currently working on a project and i have a task to validate an identifier using an ANTLR4 grammar. This part of the project if the frontend using Angular 6, and the grammar will also be compiled to a backend microservice.

The validation consist in validating a string that start with a letter|digit character, and then it can have letter|digit|underscore and finishes with a letter|digit character.

I'm currently having problems with the grammar implementation (since I have no experience in Lex) and handling the errors. Here is my grammar, and implementation for the error.

```
grammar test;

goal: identifier;

identifier: Alphanum+ Alphanumsymb* Alphanum+;

Alphanum: [a-zA-Z0-9];
Alphanumsymb: [a-zA-Z0-9_];
```

And my implementation for detecting if the string is valid according to the grammar.

```
const teststring = "2019_Test_Identifier";    
const inputStream = new ANTLRInputStream(teststring);
const lex = new lexer.TestGrammarLexer(inputStream);
const tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
const pars = new parser.TestGrammarParser(tokenStream);
pars.goal();
console.log(pars.numberOfSyntaxErrors);
if ( pars.numberOfSyntaxErrors > 0 ) {
  return false;
}
return true;
```

My problem is that even if I get the grammar right, my implementation of the error handling isn't correct and I haven't found material to study the error handling with antlr4ts.

So, if you can help me, I would appreciate feedback about the grammar (how it should be, or the problems it have atm), and about the implementation of the error handling (some info about this, because when testing, I see the ConsoleErrorListener throwing syntax error to console but my function show 0 syntax errors).

Thank you for reading and hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using ANTLR is a bit of overkill for your task. ANTLR, or any other parsing tool, is good for constructing the structure of a string, but here, you just want to know if a string is an identifier or not. If you really need ANTLR, please elaborate why and then I can help you with the error handling.

For this task, I'd suggest, you just use a regular expression like the following for testing an identifier:

```
const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

And then use it as `regex.test(str)`.

It will return `false` if the string is not accepted as an identifier.

Please note that your definition of the `identifier` in the ANTLR grammar is not correct. It requires at least two characters, because of the two `+` quantifiers, and it fails on strings of length 1 such as `a`. The regex version also fixes that.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your explination. I have the same opinion as you, currently I have my code with this regex:
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9'_']*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}$/.test()
And it is working, but I have to make a version of this functionality with Antlr4...
Any way, Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: No problem, so, could you please elaborate on what sort of error reporting do you have in mind? ANTLR will report when there is a lexical error and you can print it to the console. You can also customize the error message, But I’m not sure what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Anticipating that this backend microservice will 'do more' in the future, the current minimal grammar requirement can be met by

```
ident    : Alphanum (( Alphanum | Symb )* Alphanum )? ; 

Alphanum : [a-zA-Z0-9] ;
Symb     : '_'         ;
```

Now, the `ident` rule allows for a single character identifier, as apparently permitted by the original spec.  The `Symb` rule now represents the only content that was not shadowed by the `Alphanum` rule in the original grammar.

The lexer and parser by default include a console error listener.

Use `Recognizer#addErrorListener` to add a custom extension of `ANTLRErrorListener` that counts and reports, as desired, any errors `ConsoleErrorListener` is a source example. The same listener can be set on both the lexer and parser.

Use `Recognizer#removeErrorListeners` to first remove the console listener if console messages are unwanted.

BTW, all of the ANTLR runtimes are functionally identical and architecturally quite similar. So, any ANTLR code example in {Java, Python, ...} is going to have a nearly equivalent implementation in TypeScript.